# How do I write a diff test that only runs with "dune test", not "dune build"?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

### Goal

I want to write a test that runs as part of `dune test` but does not run
as part of `dune build` (for example, because it is slow).  This test
should have an expected output file and compare the actual output to it, and `dune promote` should be able to update the expected output.

### First attempt: implicit rules

Following the instructions in the
[manual](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests.html),
I created the following minimal `diff` test:

`dune-project`:

```
(lang dune 3.3)
```

`dune`:

```
(test (name mytest))
```

`mytest.ml`:

```
let () =
  Printf.printf "this is mytest\n"
```

`mytest.expected`:

```
xxx
```

Since `mytest.expected` exists, `dune` automatically creates a `diff`
test.  However, it runs `mytest.exe > mytest.output` as part of
`dune build`:

```
$ dune clean
$ dune build --verbose
[...]
Running[4]: (cd _build/default && ./mytest.exe) > _build/default/mytest.output
$ ls _build/default/
mytest.exe*  mytest.ml  mytest.mli  mytest.output
```

Then when I run `dune test`, it does the comparison to the output file
it already made:

```
$ dune test --verbose
[...]
Command [1] exited with code 1:
$ /usr/bin/git --no-pager diff --no-index --color=always -u _build/default/mytest.expected _build/default/mytest.output
diff --git a/_build/default/mytest.expected b/_build/default/mytest.output
index d6459e0..9dac0ea 100644
--- a/_build/default/mytest.expected
+++ b/_build/default/mytest.output
@@ -1 +1 @@
-xxx
+this is mytest
```

My goal is for `dune build` to not run the test, and only run it with
`dune test`.

### Second attempt: explicit rules

I tried explicitly writing my own rules in the `dune` file, also closely following what is in the manual:

```
(test
  (name mytest)
)

; ADDED
(rule
  (with-stdout-to tests.output
    (run ./mytest.exe)))

; ADDED
(rule
  (alias runtest)
  (action
    (diff tests.expected tests.output)
  )
)
```

but the same thing happens: `tests.output` is created by `dune build`.
(I also created `tests.expected`.)

### Third attempt: more `(alias runtest)`?

I tried making the generation rule part of `runtest`:

```
(test
  (name mytest)
)

(rule
  (alias runtest)                      ; ADDED
  (action                              ; ADDED 'action' wrapper
    (with-stdout-to tests.output
      (run ./mytest.exe)
    )
  )
)

(rule
  (alias runtest)
  (action
    (diff tests.expected tests.output)
  )
)
```

but this still creates `tests.output` during `dune build`.

### Fourth attempt: `enabled_if`

I looked at `enabled_if` but didn't see any promising condition to test.

### Fifth attempt: one rule

I tried putting all of the logic into one `(alias runtest)` rule:

```
(test
  (name mytest)
)

; COMBINED
(rule
  (alias runtest)
  (action
    (progn
      (with-stdout-to tests.output
        (run ./mytest.exe)
      )
      (diff tests.expected tests.output)
    )
  )
)
```

but not only does the test still run during `dune build` (why?), but now
`dune promote` fails if run afterward:

```
$ dune promote
Skipping promotion of _build/default/tests.output to tests.expected as the
  file is missing.
```

### A clue: tests that have output files always run during the build

After further experimentation, I found that this `dune` file:

```
(rule
  (alias runtest)
  (action
    (bash "echo test with no saved output")
  )
)

(rule
  (alias runtest)
  (action
    (with-outputs-to outputs.txt
      (bash "echo test that saves output to a file")
    )
  )
)
```

will run the first test as part of `dune test` but the second as part of `dune build`.  So my working hypothesis is any rule that has any output file will run with `dune build`.  That in turn makes it impossible to run a `diff` test as part of `dune test` (and not `dune build`).